# What complications may arise if we have different jdk for tomcat and project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am doing some REST samples and for that installed Tomcat 8. 
IDE is Eclipse Luna.

I created a maven web archetype project and found that it is using J2SE5 runtime environment and while deploying the code I see that Tomcat is using JDK 1.7.

There was no question asked about the target jdk to be used when creating the project so I was not aware of what it is using.

Does this creates problem?

As I understand the project compiled on lower version can run on the higher version but still I just want to know what complications may arise in such case.

Thanks

Comment: Probably none, now if you were using Java 1.4 or earlier I'd warn you not name anything `enum`. Also, if you're worried about it; get the same version as you intend to run in production.

Comment: Thanks Elliott for enum warning. But I won't be using any version lower than 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really about the JDK.

The maven archetype that you used to create the project has probably not provided a configuration for the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/). By default, this plugin compiles with source and target compatibility set to 1.5. The eclipse-maven plugin notices this and sets your project up with a J2SE 5 build environment in eclipse.

You can fix this in your pom.xml by including the following plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a useful info. This project is created as Dynamic Web project with version 2.5 , I tried changing it but I was not allowed to. How can I change this to a higher and may be to lower sometimes?

Comment: The only way that I know to do this is to quit eclipse and edit the `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm i using lower version of JDK until and unless you are using  API of JDK 7.